# JSON encoding for dict of dicts

Tags: python, json, serialization, python-3.x

Let us say I have a custom data structure comprising of primitive dicts. I need to serialize this using JSON. My structure is as follows:

```
path_list_dict = {(node1, node2 .. nodeN): (float1, float2, float3)}
```

So this is keyed with a tuple and the value is a tuple of three values. **Each node element in the key is a custom class object with a _*str*_ method written for it**. The wrapper dict which identifies each dict entry in path_list_dict with a key is as follows:

```
path_options_dict = {‘Path1’: {(node1, node2 .. nodeN): (float1, float2, float3)}, ‘Path2’: {(nodeA1, nodeA2 .. nodeAN): (floatA1, floatA2, floatA3)} }
```

and so on.

When I try to serialize this using JSON, of course I run into a TypeError because the inner dict has tuples as keys and values and a dict needs to have keys as strings to be serialized. This can be easily taken care of for me by inserting into the dict as the str(tuple) representation instead of just the native tuple.

What I am concerned about is that when I receive it and unpack the values, I am going to have all strings at the receiving end. The key tuple of the inner dict that consists of custom class elements is now represented as a str. Will I be able to recover the embedded data? Or is these some other way to do this better?

For more clarity, I am using this [JSON tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/json/) as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- Serialize with a custom key prefix that you can pick out and unserialize again:

  ```
  tuple_key = '__tuple__({})'.format(','.join(key))
  ```

  would produce `'__tuple__(node1,node2,nodeN)'` as a key, which you could parse back into a tuple on the other side:

  ```
  if key.startswith('__tuple__('):
       key = tuple(key[10:-1].split(','))
  ```

  Demo:

  ```
  >>> key = ('node1', 'node2', 'node3')
  >>> '__tuple__({})'.format(','.join(key))
  '__tuple__(node1,node2,node3)'
  >>> mapped_key = '__tuple__({})'.format(','.join(key))
  >>> tuple(mapped_key[10:-1].split(','))
  ('node1', 'node2', 'node3')
  ```
- Don't use dictionaries, use a list of lists:

  ```
  {'Path': [[[node1, node2 .. nodeN], [float1, float2, float3]], [...]]}
  ```

  You can build such a list simply from the `dict.items()` result:

  ```
  >>> json.dumps({(1, 2, 3): ('foo', 'bar')}.items())
  '[[[1, 2, 3], ["foo", "bar"]]]'
  ```

  and when decoding, feed the whole thing back into `dict()` while mapping each key-value list to tuples:

  ```
  >>> dict(map(tuple, kv) for kv in json.loads('[[[1, 2, 3], ["foo", "bar"]]]'))
  {(1, 2, 3): (u'foo', u'bar')}
  ```

The latter approach is more suitable for custom classes as well, as the [`JSONEncoder.default()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) will still be handed these custom objects for you to serialize back to a suitable dictionary object, which gives means that a  suitable `object_hook` passed to [`JSONDecoder()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) a chance to return fully deserialized custom objects again for those.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am using the second approach of dicts is because the paths are unique and I need those keys to retrieve them for some processing. The first dict is used for internal path finding and the keys in those dicts are unique. I need to select one of those paths in another module and have to identify which one was picked for some more post processing internally, which is why I am using the wrapper. The second approach won’t help me identify which path was selected. Hence this. Also, could you please elaborate a little more on the first approach?

Comment: Pardon my naivete. I see in all your examples, your tuple consists of strings. I know this is just to illustrate the methodology, but will custom classes retain their properties on deserialization after converting them to strings? Clearly, both methods here work perfectly for me, if that one question is resolved. And thank you once again for the lucid explanation.

Comment: @adwaraki: if your tuples do *not* contain strings but custom objects, you need to find some other way of serializing and deserializing them. That does go well beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I apologize. I should have been clearer in the question itself. I added the sentence, but should have bold faced it for clarity. Is there some place you could direct me to?

Comment: @adwaraki: You could give your custom classes a `__json__` method to convert them to a value that can be json-serialized, and a class method to restore the objects from JSON again, but to store those in tuples gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Will look into that, or in any case find a workaround. Appreciate the help. Your approach helped in another serialization method I was using. :)